# In python - how do I convert items to dict?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, dictionary

I have following list of items (key-value pairs):

```
items = [('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3)]
```

What I want to get:

```
{
  'A' : 1,
  'B' : [1,2]
  'C' : 3
}
```

My naive solution:

```
res = {}
for (k,v) in items:
     if k in res:
         res[k].append(v)
     else:
         res[k] = [v]
```

I'm looking for some optimised more pythonic solution, anyone?

Comment: Working on a list dictionary comprehension solution.

Comment: i think your solution have been simple enough

Answer (score 5):

Use could use defaultdict here.

```
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(list)
for (k,v) in items:
    res[k].append(v)
# Use as dict(res)
```

**EDIT:**

This is using groupby, but please note, **the above is far cleaner and neater to the eyes**:

```
>>> data = [('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3)]
>>> dict([(key,list(v[1] for v in group)) for (key,group) in groupby(data, lambda x: x[0])])
{'A': [1], 'C': [3], 'B': [1, 2]}
```

**Downside**: Every element is a list. Change lists to generators as needed.

---

To convert all single item lists to individual items:

```
>>> res = # Array of tuples, not dict
>>> res = [(key,(value[0] if len(value) == 1 else value)) for key,value in res]
>>> res
[('A', 1), ('B', [1, 2]), ('C', 3)]
```

Comment: Any way to avoid explicit loop?

Comment: No, anything you do will have to loop through `items`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `defaultdict`/`groupby`, the following works:

```
d = {}
for k,v in items:
   d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

Comment: Only handicap is all values are list. OP do not want them to be list if there is only one value referring to that key.

Answer (score 1):

To convert dictionary to list of items

```
dict_items = list(dict_1.items())
```

To convert the list of items back to the dictionary

```
dict2 = dict(dict_items)
```

Comment: `list(dict([('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3)]).items())`: `[('A', 1), ('C', 3), ('B', 2)]`.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to do with `defaultdict`, which can be imported from `collections`.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> items = [('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3)]
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k, v in items:
    d[k].append(v)
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'A': [1], 'C': [3], 'B': [1, 2]})
```

You *can* also use a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> d = {l: [var for key, var in items if key == l] for l in {v[0] for v in items}}
>>> d
{'A': [1], 'C': [3], 'B': [1, 2]}
```

Comment: The same comment as to the other answer - is there any way to aviod explicit for loop?

Comment: @mnowotka Damn, sorry for the repetition, but my internet is a little slow, and so I did not see it. I will give you another answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WebOb multidict implementation:

```
 >>> from webob import multidict
 >>> a = multidict.MultiDict(items)
 >>> a.getall('B')
 [1,2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it looks ugly, but it works.

```
In [1]: items = [('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3)]

In [2]: d = {}

In [3]: map(lambda i: d.update({i[0]: i[1] if d.get(i[0], i[1]) == i[1] else [d[i[0]], i[1]]}), items)
Out[3]: [None, None, None, None]

In [4]: print d
{'A': 1, 'C': 3, 'B': [1, 2]}
```

In `else` branch we can check if `d[i[0]]` returns a list.